# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 CE does not show flash builder as external model

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, intellij-idea, flash-builder, game-development

I am trying to get started with the Adobe Gaming SDK.
I have downloaded the Adobe Gaming SDK and the newest IntelliJ IDEA IDE, version 13.0.2 CE as mentioned in the title.

Following [this guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Adobe+Gaming+SDK) i should be able to import all sample projects using the 'import project' button, specifying the samples directory in the Adobe Gaming SDK. However, in the next step i do not see a 'flash builder' model to use to import these projects. How come?
It should be there, also according to the [IntelliJ IDEA web help.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-adobe-flash-builder-projects.html#d1535135e301) and also their webhelp [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/origin-of-the-sources.html).

I have a screenshot showing that flash builder is not a choice:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nramesfalhim82l/Screenshot%202014-03-13%2022.46.26.png